# Novicorp WinToFlash Lite, spyware etc

Tags: windows, malware

I used Novicorp WinToFlash Lite on Windows 7  to create a Windows 10 bootable USB memory stick.
While creating the USB drive, I noticed that WinToFlash wrote something like `adding blahblah files to the installation`.
The day after I noticed that Windows 7 has been infected by ["start my search" ad-aware](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/wintoflash-suggestor-removal/), a very intrusive one. It also disabled Avira antivirus from being loaded at boot time.

Now I don't care about the Windows 7 installation because it is a virtual machine, but I am afraid about the Windows 10 installation. Could the USB stick be infected by this malware, therefore Win10 too? 
Kaspersky antivirus runs on the Windows 10 installation, but it did not notice anything. Obviously we all know that if malware comes before an antivirus installation, the last one could not work properly

Comment: Never use 3rd Marty tools to make a Windows Bootable USB!

Follow this: http://www.fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_make_Windows_7_bootable_install_USB_stick or this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool